# Error for / java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/pubsub/PubsubScopes

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to deploy my PubSub-Maven Project to Appengine. The deployment is successfull but after the Login I get the error:

```
Error for /
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/pubsub/PubsubScopes

at com.wi.pubsubtest.util.PubsubUtils.getClient(PubsubUtils.java:80)
    at de.com.wi.pubsubtest.util.PubsubUtils.getClient(PubsubUtils.java:60)
.....
```

For packaging I use this pom:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
    <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin>
    <jetty.maven.plugin>9.4.3.v20170317</jetty.maven.plugin>
</properties>



<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>                       
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>           
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.2-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>


    <plugins>

        <plugin>                          
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
            <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>               </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Could someone please help me.......

Answer (score 1):

The `com.google.api.services.pubsub` package is exported with `google-api-services-pubsub` [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-pubsub). So you have to add it to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev356-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```